# Why are "declare -f" and "declare -a" needed in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, function, declare

Sorry for the innocent question - I'm just trying to understand...

For example - I have:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -f testfunct

testfunct () {
echo "I'm function"
}

testfunct

declare -a testarr

testarr=([1]=arr1 [2]=arr2 [3]=arr3)

echo ${testarr[@]}
```

And when I run it I get:

```
$ ./test.sh
I'm function
arr1 arr2 arr3
```

So here is a question - why do I have to (if I *have* to ...) insert `declare` here?
With it - or without it it works the same...

I can understand for example `declare -i var` or `declare -r var`. But for what is `-f` (declare function) and `-a` (declare array)?

Comment: The most common use of `declare` is inside of functions, where it behaves the same as `local` when given no flags. It can also be necessary for some data types, ie. `declare -A` for associative arrays. `declare -g` is often a useful feature when wanting to make it entirely explicit to a reader that you're *intentionally* referring to a global inside a function, rather than just forgetting to declare it and making it global implicitly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`declare -f functionname` is used to output the definition of the function `functionname`, if it exists, and absolutely not to *declare* that `functionname` is/will be a function. Look:

```
$ unset -f a # unsetting the function a, if it existed
$ declare -f a
$ # nothing output and look at the exit code:
$ echo $?
1
$ # that was an "error" because the function didn't exist
$ a() { echo 'Hello, world!'; }
$ declare -f a
a () 
{ 
    echo 'Hello, world!'
}
$ # ok? and look at the exit code:
$ echo $?
0
$ # cool :)
```

So in your case, `declare -f testfunct` will do nothing, except possibly if `testfunct` exists, it will output its definition on stdout.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, the -a option alone does not have any practical relevance, but I think it's a plus for readability when declaring arrays. It becomes more interesting when it is combined with other options to generate arrays of a special type.

For example:

```
# Declare an array of integers
declare -ai int_array

int_array=(1 2 3)

# Setting a string as array value fails
int_array[0]="I am a string"

# Convert array values to lower case (or upper case with -u)
declare -al lowercase_array

lowercase_array[0]="I AM A STRING"
lowercase_array[1]="ANOTHER STRING"

echo "${lowercase_array[0]}"
echo "${lowercase_array[1]}"

# Make a read only array
declare -ar readonly_array=(42 "A String")

# Setting a new value fails
readonly_array[0]=23
```

Comment: Apparently `-l` and `-u` are only bash 4+.

Answer (score 5):

`declare -f` allows you to list all defined functions (or sourced) and their contents.

Example of use:

```
[ ~]$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

f(){
    echo "Hello world"
}

# print 0 if is defined (success)
# print 1 if isn't defined (failure)
isDefined(){
    declare -f "$1" >/dev/null && echo 0 || echo 1
}

isDefined f
isDefined g
[ ~]$ ./test.sh 
0
1
[ ~]$ declare -f
existFunction () 
{ 
    declare -f "$1" > /dev/null && echo 0 || echo 1
}
f () 
{ 
    echo "Hello world"
}
```

However as smartly said gniourf_gniourf below : it's better to use `declare -F` to test the existence of a function.

Comment: To check whether a function exists, it's probably better to use `declare -F`.