# Using "declare" in Zsh

Tags: zsh

I am following this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742842/5057251
for typeset (or declare) in ZSH, not BASH.

```sh
#Declare (or typeset) an array of integers
#declare -ai int_array
typeset -ai int_array
int_array=(1 2 3)
echo "${int_array[@]}"
```

Then

```sh
# Attempt to change 1st element to string. (expect to fail)
int_array[1]="Should fail" || echo "error: ${LINENO}"
echo "${int_array[@]}"
```

Bash finds the error, gracefully reports error and lineno, prints:

```
1 2 3
```

But Zsh accepts, prints:

```
Should fail 2 3
```

Not sure why different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. In bash, and zsh, assigning a string to an integer variable causes that string to be evaluated as an arithmetic expression. Thus, this is not an error:

   ```
   $ typeset -i foo
   $ foo="bar"
   ```

   If `bar` was a variable previously set to an arithmetic expression, then `bar`'s expansion would be evaluated as such:

   ```
   $ bar=10+2
   $ typeset -i foo
   $ foo="bar"
   $ echo "$foo"
   12
   ```

   The error in your assignment, of course, is that there's no way to expand `Should fail` like that. If it were, say, `Should - fail` (an arithmetic expression subtracting the value of the two variables `Should` and `fail`, for example, it would still work:

   ```
   $ foo="Should - fail"
   $ echo "$foo"
   0
   ```
2. The second problem is that nothing in [the zsh docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Parameters) indicate that `-i` may be set for an entire array, and so the `-a` in `-ai` is ignored:

   ```
   bash-5.0$ typeset -ai foo
   bash-5.0$ declare -p foo
   declare -ai foo=([0]="0")  # the previous value was retained in the array
   ```

   vs zsh:

   ```
   % typeset -ai foo
   % foo[1]=10
   % foo[2]=20
   % declare -p foo
   typeset -i foo=20  # treated as a normal variable, not array
   ```

   What you're seeing is essentially `int_array` being redeclared as an array (without any qualifiers) when you do `int_array=(1 2 3)`:

   ```
   % foo=(1 2 3)
   % declare -p foo
   typeset -a foo=( 1 2 3 )
   ```

Comment: Tricky.  `declare -p foo`    # very helpful to see what shell thinks

Answer (score 1):

Using zsh typeset can produce a few possible outcomes:
 -   no errors, works (yeah!).
 -   errors, script fails (fix!).
 -   no errors, but **unexpected** behavior.  (scratch head)

As an example of last category, this produces no errors, but the `typeset -p` reveals -i is ignored.

```
{                                                                                                                                                                        
unset int_array                                                                                                                                                          
typeset -ia int_array                                                                                                                                                    
int_array=(1 2 3)                                                                                                                                                        
echo $? "-Point A"                                                                                                                                                       
typeset -p int_array                                                                                                                                                     

    } always {                                                                                                                                                           

echo $? "-Point B"                                                                                                                                                       
typeset -p int_array                                                                                                                                                     
(( TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0 ))                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                        
echo $? "-Point C"                                                                                                                                                       
echo "survived"
```

produces

```
 0 -Point A                                                                                                                                                               
 typeset -a int_array=( 1 2 3 )                                                                                                                                           
 0 -Point B                                                                                                                                                               
 typeset -a int_array=( 1 2 3 )                                                                                                                                           
 0 -Point C                                                                                                                                                               
 survived
```

The first line unsets int_array.   The typeset command declares
 int_array to be both an array and int, which is not what zsh allows.  The next
 line assigns int_array to a value.   There is no error as the `$?` tells us,
 but close examination of final `typeset  -p int_array` reveals what actually
 happened.

With a small change, we can produce errors and use the `always` block and
 `typeset -p` to find more details.

```
{                                                                                                                                                                        
unset int_array                                                                                                                                                          
typeset -ia int_array=(1 2 3) # error                                                                                                                                    
echo $? "-Point A"                                                                                                                                                       
typeset -p int_array 

      } always {                                                                                                                                                           

echo $? "-Point B"                                                                                                                                                       
typeset -p int_array                                                                                                                                                     
(( TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0 ))                                                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                                                        
echo $? "-Point C"                                                                                                                                                       
echo "survived"
```

```
040_declare_version2.sh:typeset:135: int_array: inconsistent type for assignment                                                                                         
1 -Point B                                                                                                                                                               
040_declare_version2.sh:typeset:140: no such variable: int_array                                                                                                         
1 -Point C                                                                                                                                                               
survived
```

The only difference is int_array was given a value in the faulty `typeset -ia` statement.
 This produces errors, and the script jumps to the `always block.`
 The `(( TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0))` allows the script to continue
 and not terminate, but the error is still reported at "Point C".

To check shell version:

```
$SHELL --version                                                                                                                                                         
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)
```