# What is the the use of declare command in initializing an array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, declare

```sh
arr=("Jane Doe" "John Doe" "Janet")
```

```sh
declare -a arr=("Jane Doe" "John Doe" "Janet")
```

What is the difference between the two array initialization in bash?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, yes it answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: No, actually, it didn't, because there *is* a difference.

Answer (score 5):

The two array initializations presented, supposing that they in fact *are* initializations (see below), mean exactly the same thing *if the `declare` occurs at the top level*.  When `declare` is executed inside a function, however, without the `-g` option, it is equivalent to `local`, declaring a variable that is local to the function.
On the other hand, the direct initialization declares a global variable regardless of where it appears.

```
example() {
  direct=(a b c)
  declare -a indirect=(d e f)

  #prints a
  echo "$direct"

  #prints d
  echo "$indirect"
}

example

#prints a
echo "$direct"

#prints nothing
echo "$indirect"
```

Of course, `local` would be clearer where the intention is in fact to declare a local variable.  `declare` is more interesting in combination with others of its options, including when those are combined with `-a`.  Consider `declare -a -r foo=(1 2 3)`, for example.

---

At the beginning, I raised the possibility that one or both of the commands in question might not be an "initialization".  Here I am drawing a distinction between *initialization*, which defines an initial value for a variable that did not previously exist, and *assignment*, which changes the value of a variable that already does exist.  If I had been particularly careful then I would have noted that although the `declare` version *contains* an initialization, the overall command is not well characterized as an initialization.

This brings forward another distinction between the two commands in question:

- the direct assignment version serves as an initialization of a new (global) variable only if neither a global nor an in-scope local variable with the given name already exists.  Where a variable with the given name *does* exist, it is merely an assignment.  On the other hand,
- an initialization in a `declare` command serves *only* as an initialization.  If the declared variable already exists then any initial value specified via the `declare` command is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
arr=("Jane Doe" "John Doe" "Janet")
```

```sh
declare -a arr=("Jane Doe" "John Doe" "Janet")
```

Both of the above statements can be used to create an array.
The second one with the `declare` command provides readability in declaring arrays.

Elaboration on that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742842/13798537